# SQL Queries comparison

Tags: sql

```
Tables A and B in action.
A [commonfield, otherfields]
B [commonfield]
```

Query 1

```
select
        A.otherfields
from
        A,B
where
        A.commonfield = B.commonfield
        and some filters ( A.commonfield )
```

Query 2

```
select
        A.otherfields
from
        A
where
        A.commonfield in ( select B.commonfield from B )
        and some filters ( A.commonfield )
```

Query 1 is equivalent to Query 2. Which is better with regards to (a) memory usage and (b) speed ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: memory usage the second query is better, since you already restrict your selection for B and then based on the results you query A.

Comment: Please move into the 21st century and stop using implicit joins. They are a SQL Antipattern and are harder to maintain and much easier to make mistakes with.

Comment: And the perfornace issue may depend on what database you are using. So  we can't answer that question until we know that answer.

Comment: Using oracle, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

The best and the ANSI Standard way of doing it would be

Query #3:

```
select
        A.otherfields
from
        A
inner join
        B ON A.commonfield = B.commonfield
where
        some filters ( A.commonfield )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possiblity:

```
SELECT
        A.otherfields
FROM
        A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE A.commonfield = B.commonfield)
        AND some filters ( A.commonfield )
```

Where exists tend to be fastest in SQL Server but not in all databases.

I would test all possiblities (except the one using implicit joins which is a poor programming technique all by itself and should not be used unless you have such an old database that you can't use an explicit join)) to determine the best performance with your particualr database and setup.

Answer (score 0):

Those two queries will be compiled before execution.

The performance will be dependent of your SQL Server Vendor implementation of the query compiler.

One vendor may optimize both to the same code to be executed.

I'm using SQL Server 2000 and both expressions resulted in equivalent code with equivalent performance.

Answer (score 0):

Query 1 is *not* equivalent to Query 2!

Query1 will return multiple rows when there are multiple matches in B.  Query 2 will only return the rows in A, with no duplicates.

Since these do not return equivalent result sets, I don't think it is a good idea to compare their performance.

However, Query 1 will probably perform better, because it is not doing duplicate elimination.  On the other hand, if you have appropriate indexes, then the two might be similar or Query 2 might even be better.